# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined in Laravel & vue.js

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, pusher

> Hello friends I am tired of getting this error when i count a length of notification by using vue.js and Laravel it show error,Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined plz help me. here is my code.

store.js

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
state: {
    nots: []

},
getters: {
    all_nots(state) {
          return state.nots
    },
    all_nots_count(state) {
          return state.nots.length
    },

},
mutations: {
    add_not(state, not) {
          state.nots.push(not)
    },
}
})
```

UnreadNots.vue

```
<template>
  <li>
        <a href="/notifications">
              Unread notifications
              <span class="badge">{{ all_nots_count }}</span>
        </a>
  </li>
  </template>
 <script>
  export default {
        mounted() {
              this.get_unread()
        },
         methods: {
              get_unread() {
                    this.$http.get('/get_unread')
                        .then( (nots) => {
                              nots.body.forEach( (not) => {
                                    this.$store.commit('add_not', not)
                              })
                        })
              }
        },
        computed: {
              all_nots_count() {
               return this.$store.getters.all_nots_count
              }
        }

    }
</script>
```

web.php

```
Route::get('get_unread', function(){
    return Auth::user()->unreadNotification;
  });
```

Comment: Just `console.log(nots)` and it will be obvious that it doesnt have `body`

Comment: i got blank data

Comment: Yeap so what's that tell you? Probably nothing is being sent from your server. Check network tab in your browser console and see what the call is returning

Comment: Please give a screenshot what is returned from `/get_unread`. You can open it in your browser or postman.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the error, you need to test your return value to make sure it has everything you're expecting.

```
if(nots && nots.body && nots.body.length){
    nots.body.forEach( (not) => {
       this.$store.commit('add_not', not)
    })
}
```

Comment: Sure. That's another problem. You're going to need to grub around in your api to see why there's no data coming back.

Comment: Provide more contents to support your answer, adding merely a code snippet doesn't seems to be a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because `forEach` expects an array. It's undefined. That's clear from the error.

One possible way to fix this is a check if `nots.body` is an array and has items.

```
this.$http.get('/get_unread')
    .then(nots => {
        if (Array.isArray(nots.body) && nots.body.length) {
            nots.body.forEach(not => {
                this.$store.commit('add_not', not)
            })
        }
    })
```

Another tip is to not use underscores in your urls. Google for example will treat words separated by underscore as one word, but for hyphens they will consider it two words. `get_unread` should be `get-unread`. This might not be a big issue, but if you do this for other urls like `my_blog_title` then it's a bigger issue.

A better solution for notifications like this is a REST style approach like `http://mywebsite.com/user/notifications/unread`

Comment: all_nots_count:0 why it is so?

Comment: Because you don't have any data returned from the server, so when it tries to `forEach` them they are trying to foreach `undefined` not any items in an array. This is why it fails. This isn't a vue issue, it's an issue with your backend. Try `dd(Auth::user()->unreadNotification)` (sure it's not unreadNotification**s**?)

Comment: i have use in route

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying or if you've even understood what I've said

Comment: i have used in web.php just like as  return Auth::user()->unreadNotifications;

Answer (score 0):

don't use nots.body use nots.data.
I had the same issue 5 minutes ago